# composer error Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.for Madeline

Tags: ubuntu, composer-php

I want to [install MadelineProto library](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/#installation).

when I want to use my library in phpstorm, it warns me about some method. It said the method doesn't exist and I think madeline wasn't install.

When I want to install that from composer it returns error.

#### composer.json:

```js
{
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/danog/phpseclib"
    }, {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto"
    }
],
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
    "name": "danog/madelineproto",
    "description": "PHP implementation of telegram's MTProto protocol.",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "AGPL-3.0",
    "homepage": "https://daniil.it/MadelineProto",
    "keywords": ["telegram", "mtproto", "protocol", "bytes", "messenger", "client", "PHP", "video", "stickers", "audio", "files", "GB"],
    "conflict": {
        "krakjoe/pthreads-polyfill": "*"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.0",
        "danog/primemodule": "dev-master",
        "danog/magicalserializer": "dev-master",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "dev-master#200c2a9",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
        "erusev/parsedown": "^1.6",
        "rollbar/rollbar": "~1.1",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-sockets": "*",
        "ext-xml": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^3.1"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "ext-libtgvoip": "Install the php-libtgvoip extension to make phone calls (https:/github.com/danog/php-libtgvoip)"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Daniil Gentili",
            "email": "daniil@daniil.it"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "danog\\MadelineProto\\": "src/"
        },
        "files": [
            "src/Socket.php",
            "src/Collectable.php",
            "src/Threaded.php",
            "src/Volatile.php",
            "src/Thread.php",
            "src/Worker.php",
            "src/Pool.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

When I run

```
composer require "danog/madelineproto:dev-master"
```

it returns:

```js
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for danog/madelineproto dev-master -> satisfiable by danog/madelineproto[dev-master].
    - danog/madelineproto dev-master requires danog/primemodule dev-master -> satisfiable by danog/primemodule[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.


Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to install [MadelineProto](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/docs/INSTALLATION.html):

**1. Simple**

```
<?php
if (!file_exists('madeline.php')) {
    copy('https://phar.madelineproto.xyz/madeline.php', 'madeline.php');
}
require_once 'madeline.php';
```

**2. Simple (manual)**

Download [madeline.php](https://phar.madelineproto.xyz/madeline.php), put it in the same directory as your script, and then put the following code in your PHP file:

```
<?php
require_once 'madeline.php';
```

**3. Composer from scratch**

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "yourname/yourproject",
    "description": "Project description",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "danog/madelineproto": "^5.1"
    },
    "license": "AGPL-3.0-only",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Daniil Gentili",
            "email": "daniil.gentili.dg@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Your\\Project\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Then run:

```
composer update
```

**Put the following code in your PHP file:**

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

**4. Composer from existing project**

Simply require the package:

```
composer require danog/madelineproto
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the new [composer installation guide](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/#composer-installation)